# interface task error CS0050

Tags: c#, interface, task, public

I have this code

```
public interface IWebInterfaceService
{
    Task<LoadModel> GetContentAsync(string query);
}
```

"GetContentAsync" show error:

> Error  CS0050  Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'Task<LoadModel>' is less accessible than method 'IWebInterfaceService.GetContentAsync(string)'

Removing the `public` keyword helps but I want the interface to be public. Adding `public` before `Task<LoadModel>` is not possible.

Comment: Thanks but my question is about Task<LoadModel>. In topic you mark as solution is not Task<xxxx>. I was not able to solve my problem by reading that article. But thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because LoadModel is less accessible than your interface.

Make LoadModel public.